# VisualVM deployed

Tags: tomcat7, visualvm

I would like to analyze my tomcat's threads in a web application tool.

I've used visualvm but it's an application installed on the client. At moment, I need a tool like visualvm but installed on the server, simply a web application tool.

Comment: you know that you can start visualvm on your client and have it show the values of the JRE on your server ?

Comment: Yes, but I want a web application tool

Comment: I think it might help if you add to your question if you have the sourcecode for the applications you want to monitor and how you want to analyze the threads (for example: is seeing them, their name and the status enough). And: is it the threads of tomcat you want to see or those of the applications running.

Comment: Is your question still unanswered ?

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat manager app enables you to create a thread dump. You can deploy it alongside your applications.

To see the thread dump you simply open the url `http://localhost:8080/manager/text/threaddump`. Like the manager this URL can be protected by authorization.

See the [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Thread_Dump) for details.